# How do you get to see UV mapping for a texture applied to a side of a human body made of hundreds of faces?

Tags: uv

I have a human body and I want to add a texture to a side of it. The body is separated in hundreds of faces, vertexs, etc. When I select hundreds of faces in one side of the body (the back of the human body to start) and apply a texture to it, it works, but not in the proportions and mappings I want at all. So I would like to see that in the UV editor, but I see nothing, I suppose because I'm selecting hundreds of faces at the same time which are in one side of the human body (the back of the human body) . This is different than when you assign a texture to a side of a cube because you are selecting only one face so you automatically see the mapping in the UV editor.

How do you deal with these situations?
How do you get to see UV mapping for a texture applied to a side of a human body made of hundreds of faces?

Comment: The difficulty you're having is one of the reasons that sculpted (or otherwise high-poly) objects are retopologized before UV mapping, animation, or other tasks that high-poly load can make difficult.  Although you can search the Blender Stack Exchange or look through its retopology tag, if you're unfamiliar with it you should probably look for some Blender retopology beginner tutorials on YouTube or forums like Blender Artists.

Comment: Although @KickAir8p has a point here, it's not that you "_see nothing_" in the UV editor because you're "_selecting hundreds of faces_". The UV editor can show hundreds of selected faces, the questions are: is your object UV unwrapped correctly or does it even have a UV map?